# Simple vb function crashes SSIS and give "unexpeced end tag error"

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssis

I am at a loss to what the issue is on this one, it is a very simple function and when I close the editor in SSIS I get the "Unexpected end tag, line 95, postions 87, (mscorlib)" error. once I get this error I am no longer able to open the script task to edit the code. I have tried this on several machines. and it either crashes SSIS or gives me an error.

```
Function XMLWrapper(ByVal name As String, ByVal value As String, ByVal cdata As Boolean) As String
    Dim Result As String
    If value.Length > 0 Then
        If cdata = True Then
            Result = vbTab & "<field name=" & name & "><![CDATA[" & value & "]]></field>"
        Else '<-- Line 95 where i get the error
            Result = vbTab & "<field name=" & name & ">" & value & "</field>"
        End If
    Else
        Result = ""
    End If
    Return Result
End Function
```

Comment: If I create an SSIS package, add a Script Task with the above code, I should get the same issue? Or is the problem only encountered when you use the method? If it's the latter, I think we'll need more information about what data is being supplied, how it's being used, etc.

Comment: Also, which version of ssis are you using? 2005, 2008/2008R2 or 2012?

Comment: I suspect that the line 95 the error message mentions is actually line 95 of the XML file you're generating, rather than line 95 of the script file that's generating it, as the error describes a problem with XML formatting. Check the XML you're generating to see if it makes sense. (For example, if your "name" parameter in this function isn't already wrapped in quotes, you'll produce badly-formed XML, as `<field name=whatever>...</field>` is wrong (`<field name="whatever">...</field>` would be okay.) Consider using standard XML generation methods to generate XML, rather than text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

This error is actually being thrown by saving the code into the XML SSIS package!

You can fool it by splitting your strings like so

```
    XMLResult = Replace(XMLResult, "URL>", "URL" & ">" & "<" & "![CDATA")

    XMLResult = Replace(XMLResult, "<" & "/" & "JobDetailURL" & ">", "]]" & ">" & "<" & "/" & "JobDetailURL" & ">")
    XMLResult = Replace(XMLResult, "<" & "/" & "CompanyURL" & ">", "]]" & ">" & "<" & "/" & "CompanyURL" & ">")
    XMLResult = Replace(XMLResult, "<" & "/" & "CompanyImageURL" & ">", "]]" & ">" & "<" & "/" & "CompanyImageURL" & ">")
```